# Spring security regex patern matcher and '/' character

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

In my spring security configuration I have

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" path-type="regex">
...
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

This pattern matches the path "/admin" as well, even if this string is not produced by the regex "/admin/*" (there is no slash at the end). Why is that? I found no documentation about it. Does regex path matching have any other peculiarity like this one?
I am using Spring Security 3.0.

**EDIT**
I obviously was mistaking "*" for ".*". Should have taken a nap instead of asking it here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` in a regex means "match the preceding character *zero* or more times", so your regex does match the string "/admin".

You probably want to use `+` which means "match the preceding character *one* or more times".

Comment: True! For some reason I thought I was writing ".*" and not simply "*". Missed a character there!

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior Right, that makes more sense than my suggestion of using `+`. :-)